# Windows Form Application convert to .Net Framework 4.0 to 2.0

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

While creating a Windows Form Application, I selected target to .Net Framework 4.0. Now I would like to build it to .Net Framework 2.0. How can I do it using Visual Studio 2010?

It is a VB.Net project. **I could not see "Target Framework"**. For my C# projects, I can see the "Target Framework" property.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For C# project, if you go to the project properties, you will find `Target Framework` on `Application` tab. Switch it to `.NET Framework 2.0`.

[image]

Try to build and remove unsupported namespaces.

If you used any features specific to .NET 4, you will have to fix it manually.

**[Edit]** As you mentioned that you use VB.NET.

For VB.NET go to project properties, hit `Advanced Compile Options...` to the `Compile` tab.

[image]

Select target framework:

[image]

Comment: It is a VB.Net project. I could not see "Target Framework". For my C# projects, I can see the "Target Framework" property.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project in Solution Explorer and go to properties change the Target framework in the Application tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience after switching the target framework, the core references will not be updated.

For example I changed from C# library 4.0 back to 3.5 (so I could work it with SP2010), and found it left CSharp.exe (a 4.0 assembly) as an undefined reference.

I recreated it from scratch and found the set of core references is different.

To be safe, I would recommend recreating your project and re-adding the project files after.

But who knows, you may get lucky. :D Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i've been try to upgrade my project from .net 2.0 to 4.0, and yeah the reference is still targeting .net 2.0. 
The solution open *.csproj (project file) with notepad, and change

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="2.0">
```

into

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
```

Hope this help