# Displaying a Chart on a Canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, charts

I have seen an answer regarding adding a Visual to a canvas but I am trying to add a Chart to my canvas. The compiler complains about not being able to convert a chart to a UIElement. Here is my code:
`pieChartCanvas.Children.Add(pieChart);`

What do I need to do to display the chart on the canvas?

Comment: UIElement is Framework.  So you have to convert from Windows Form to Framework.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235616/windows-form-application-convert-to-net-framework-4-0-to-2-0

Comment: @jdweng: Thank you for replying. I am using WPF...and to be honest, I don't really understand what the discussion in that link really told me...?

Comment: One Framework controls can be used.  So you need to convert any controls like you chart to a Framework object.

Comment: @jdweng: I am already using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: UIElement is Net 2.0.  So a conversion is needed to convert the chart/canvas to an older Net version.